# How to change or extend express-graphql context without recreating the request handler?

Tags: node.js, express-graphql

howto change/extend express-graphql context without  recreating the request handler ?

```js
/** */
const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});
/** */
export default (req: any, res: any, context: any) => {
  console.log("context:", context);
  const handler = graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
    context: {
      req,
      ...context,
    },
  });  
  return handler(req, res);
};
```

I noticed graphqlHTTP accepts a promise for options.
Not sure how is this going to help.
as the `(req)=> Promise<Otions>` (options-callback) would need to be built again for every request anyway ?
mI missing something ?

NOTE: please ignore the context building implementation it could be anything you like

This seems to do the trick, partially...

```js
/** */
const handler = graphqlHTTP(async (req: any) => {  
  return {
    schema,
    graphiql: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
    /** this doesn't work */
    context: {
      req,
      session: await getSession({ req }),
    },
  };
});
```

but all the context dependencies need to be declared upfront.
Rebuilding the callback will require to build the handler.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the lack of feedback ... I'm not sure if I'm asking something 'obvious' or obviously wrong :).

But, ...anyway, this is the closest I've found

```js
/** */
const handler = graphqlHTTP(async (req) => {  
  return {
    schema,
    graphiql: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
    /** this doesn't work */
    context: {
      req,
      session: await getSession({ req }),
    },
  };
});
```

...still, lets you alone to build your own dependency graph by external means, like dynamic import, require's , dependency injection, singletons, HOC ...etc

Comment: sorry if I'm wrong but I'll accept my own answer, that doesn't really answers much ...